# Google play: "Item not found" error on installing application to android 2.x device

Tags: android, google-play

My application uses module SDK Android 4.2.2 Platform, but in AndroidManifest.xml I have

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

I am using google-play-services-lib in my application and Google Maps API V2.

I am using tester's account to login to Google Play and try to install my apk (status -  alpha) to android 2.3 device and get "Item not found error" when clicking to "Upload from Google Play" button, but this app installs well to android 4.x devices.
On the other hand, I can install it on all devices (android 2.x devices included) from USB or using http://testflightapp.com.

My device included to supported devices list on Google Play, API level 8+.
Can anyone suggest any possible causes for this error? Many thanks.

Comment: Please show users what you have tried so far for better answers.

Comment: you need to install google play services https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Comment: @BirajZalavadia, I have latest installed version of google play services. Couldn't it be any another reason?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this problem by reset my phone to factory settings. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: this doesn't sound as a solution, not every developer can simply reset their testing devices. If it only works for you, then it's not a real answer that can contribute to the community.